# marklogic "getting started" app returns 404 on mac

Tags: osx-yosemite, marklogic

I'm running MarkLogic 8 (developer edition) on Mac OS 10.10.1.

I'm a beginner with ML, and I'm reading the "Getting Started" material in the online docs, in particular the section "Sample XQuery Application that Runs Directly Against an App Server."

I created the "TestServer" app server just fine, following the instructions. I then copied and pasted the text for the four XQuery files in the exercise, load.xqy, dump.xqy etc.

My local copies of the four .xqy files are under ~/Library/MarkLogic/Apps/Test, per the instructions. Read and execute permissions are open along the entire filepath, down to the .xqy files themselves.

When I request http://localhost:8005/Test/load.xqy, as instructed, I get a 404 Not Found response.

lsof -i :8005 indicates that MarkLogic is indeed listening on port 8005.

I checked the TestServer configuration against the instructions, disabled and re-enabled TestServer, stopped and re-started ML--always with the same result: 404 Not Found.

I haven't been able to find anything in either the ML mail archives or Stackoverflow to get me past this sticking point.

Any ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a permission issue. Does it work when you run it as the admin user?

Have check to make sure the files are loaded into the modules database?

Also check the permission got set with the correct role for those file.

Check to see that user that is running the app has the role that you used when setting permission on those file.

Comment: Also check that the appserver is configured to use that modules database and has a root of /

Comment: Thanks, Tyler! It turns out that there was a bug in the doc. It said to set the app root at "Test", and then it gave "localhost:8005/Test/load.xqy" as the URL to hit load.xqy. Removing "Test" from the URL made it work. (It was a MarkLogic guy at the ML World 2015 San Francisco who found the issue.)

I'll definitely keep your hints in mind if I run into 404s in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for us:

In the **TestServer** configuration instead of just putting **Test** in root field, put **Apps/Test/** which is the location of the 4 files (load.xqy,dump.xqy, update-form.xqy and update-write.xqy relative to the MarkLogic installation directory -- in our case, centos, this was at /opt/MarkLogic/)

And then issued this command

```
chmod +r *.xqy
```

Comment: Just saw this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you follow all the instructions correctly just remove the Test from the url. If yours is "http://localhost:8005/Test/load.xqy" make it "http://localhost:8005/load.xqy"

Comment: got the help from this url http://general.developer.marklogic.narkive.com/KbeYd59U/marklogic-dev-general-create-http-server-tutorial